# useState variable not setting on the first run of the snippet of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a windows 10 calculator clone in React, and I am stuck on this snippet below:

```
function Calculator(){ //for providing context of the situation

    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState('0')
    const [aMath, setAMath] = useState('')
    const [bMath, setBMath] = useState('')
    const [calcShow, setCalcShow] = useState('')
    const [symbolMath, setSymbolMath] = useState('')
    const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(true)

    const handleClick = (e) => {
    ...
        else if(symbol === '+'){
            if(aMath === '')
                 setAMath(currentValue)
            else
                 setBMath(currentValue)
            setCalcShow(aMath+symbol+bMath)
            setNewValue(true)
            console.log({a: aMath,b: bMath,currentValue})
            setSymbolMath(symbol)
        }
...
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the setAMath and setBMath are executed fully, on the third or second press of '+' button, and everything else runs just fine. I want an instant change of the bMath variable. The console.log() shows, that currentValue updates fine, but the rest has initial state of '' and changes on the situation mentioned earlier. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

### **It's because [Reactjs's update batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) mechanism**

---

When updating state within an eventHandler like onChange, onClick,.etc.., React will batch all of `setState` into one:

Place your log right before the `return` function to see that lastest value.

Or inside a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("aMath", aMath);
},[aMath]);
```

**But this behaviour will be changed in Reactjs 18 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I understand, that in order to make an update to the aMath so, that my calculator will instantly display it, I need to use useEffect?

Comment: I’d say so. But why don’t you just display it directly but need to rely on the state?

Comment: I use the calcShow to display '2 + 2 =' on the upper screen and I need A and B to update only on the press of operator button (+, -, x etc.), like on the windows 10 calculator. Also, it will show only 'A +' if I only press plus not equals.

Comment: Yeah, then just use it directly in the JSX

Comment: But it is using JSX, and now I need to figure out how to make it update as I want with useEffect
`<div className={${styles.display}}>{calcShow}</div>`